# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'rpartition' when setting directory

Tags: python, django

After typing

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
```

in settings.py I get the error in the tittle.

I tried with STATICDIR but it still doesn't work. I am pretty new to django so I don't really know other ways to fix it.

EDIT: turns out I tried to install the template folder in the INSTALLED APPs thingy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can try following way:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

And in your template, load the static using following tag:

```
{% load static %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` (and all other path-related options) must be a string, not a Path.

Cast it in the assignment:

```
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / "staticfiles")
```